# vim-tagbar doesn't jump to method definitions, at least for ruby

Tags: vim, vim-plugins, ctags

I use the vim plugin tag-bar but it doesn't seem to work for ruby, not completely at least. At first it didn't work at all but by changing the config to use ripper-ctags like so:

```
let g:tagbar_type_ruby = {
    \ 'kinds' : [
        \ 'm:modules',
        \ 'c:classes',
        \ 'd:describes',
        \ 'C:contexts',
        \ 'f:methods',
        \ 'F:singleton methods'
    \ ],
        \ 'ctagsbin':  'ripper-tags',
        \ 'ctagsargs': ['-f', '-']
\ }
```

I'm able to get it to display the tags, but pressing enter on the tag in the tag bar doesn't jump to the method definition/ constant, instead it just jumps me to the top of the file and nothing else.

P.S. I do have ctags installed, just incase you're wondering

P.P.S. It did work completely properly but I did something a while back and now it doesn't work at all with normal ctags, I'm guessing it's a config option or a plugin but I don't know what at all is doing it, if you want to check, here are my [dotfiles](http://github.com/thermatix/dotfiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ripper-tags`'s default output doesn't contain line number information, I opened a pull request to fix it: https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags/pull/65.
You could try it by:

1. Clone my repo and switch to `add-line-number-to-vim-formatter` branch
2. Build and install the gem locally

Then tagbar should work fine.

Comment: AWESOME SAUCE! whilst this doesn't solve why I have to use ripper tags in the first place (which to be fair isn't really the question of OP), I will take this any way, thanks!